# Sava search query and stay on same page

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with my php code. I have tried everything and nothing works.
I want that the form will save the search query into the database but but i canot use `action="search.php"` since the result is displayed on the index.php page so it need's to stay on the index page and execut the save.

The form:

```
<form class="form-domain" role="form" action="search.php" method=post>

<!-- Search input -->
<div class="search-input">
<span class="www">www.</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-domain" placeholder="vasa-nova-domena" name="ime_domene">
<div class="domain-extension">
<select class="form-control" name="koncnica">
<option value=".com" selected="">.com</option>
<option value=".si">.si</option>
</select>
</div>
</div><!-- /.search-input -->

<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="poslji" name="preglej" type="submit"><strong>PREVERI</strong></button>

</form>
```

Right after this form comes the php result so i need to stay on the index.php to have the result of the search visible but the same time i want the input/search that was given saved into the database.

I hope this wasen't to complicated. :)

Comment: What you are looking for is "client side scripting" and "ajax requests" for this. There is lots of information for that stuff on google :-) This cannot be done by means of php alone. But no worries: php and javascript work together hand in hand and you will learn to use it in no time.

Comment: Thank you @arkascha. :)
That sound's really fun... not. :) But i will give it a try.

Comment: Well 1. it is easier than it sounds, 2. there is endless information and examples about this and 3. you _will_ master and enjoy it!

Comment: lol, it's working! :D I can't believe it. Thank you @arkascha.
Gone to read the term "client side scripting" and it was pretty clear what i need to do. :)

Comment: I am _really_ impressed by that fast success. Wow!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","<?php include 'search.php';?>",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>
```